# Silverstripe ExactMatchFilter example

Tags: filter, filtering, silverstripe

I have a list of dataobjects of which I'm trying to return all objects that match certain years e.g all objects that match 2015, 2013, 2002 etc

I first attempted to use `ExactMatchMulti` as per the question here: [Silverstripe - filter DataObject list by many many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127486/silverstripe-filter-dataobject-list-by-many-many-relationship)

However this has now been deprecated and Silverstripe suggests I use `ExactMatchFilter` instead. However I can't find much documentation/code usages of `ExactMatchFilter` so I'm not sure how to use it. Replacing `ExactMatchMulti` with `ExactMatchFilter` throws an exception.

```
$things->filter('PublicationDate:ExactMatchFilter', $filters);
```

Where `$filters` is just a simple array of years.

Does anyone have any examples or suggestions for this?

(Using 3.2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was actually very simple and just an oversight. Working example:

```
public function getPagesByFilter() {
    $filters = array('2015', '2014');
    Page::get()->filterAny('PublicationDate:PartialMatch', $filters);
}
```

The simple and obvious thing, as mentioned above was to use filterAny rather than just filter. This will return all pages with publication dates in 2015 and 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Exception details are good things to add to the question.

I think using exact match filter on a date field wouldn't work logically as you think. Does the field exactly contain 2015, or doest it contain a date timestamp? I'm presuming the latter as your field name is PublicationDate.

This is one we used to filter by year:

`NewsItem()->get()->filter('Date:StartsWith', $year)`

Or you could just filter with a greater than and lower than sets also by years.

EDIT:

The sample query is not tested on 3.2.1 but should be valid.

By using filter any you can get multiple with OR (based on https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/#filterany):

```
 NewsItem()->get()->filterAny("Date:StartsWith",array('2015','2014'));
```

Then generate the array with the right years how do you want.

Tip:

Use ->sql() to see what is the sql query: 
    `Debug::dump(NewsItem()->get()->filterAny("Date:StartsWith",array('2014','2015'))->sql());`

EDIT: revised to fix double key issue.

Comment: Problem is I'd then have to manually iterate over each provided year and store the result for that into a new object and return that new object, as there could be many years. This is what I'm trying to avoid if possible.  ```PartialMatch``` is also better than ```StartsWith``` as it allows the date format to be more flexible.

Comment: @Peavers That was a sample how to filter by a date but I added a sample to use the filterAny that gives you the OR queries. Should work.. not tested.

Comment: Almost right, but you're duplicating your array keys so no go there. Correct answer below

Comment: @Peavers Its right still and sufficient as an answer what one can improve on. Of course the shorthand version is cleaner but this illustrates more how to use the filters also in different cases. You could mark your own as the answer but I'd still appreciate a vote up.

Comment: Your answer actually returns a pretty nasty SQL error. I'm also still lost as to how this would work with an array with identical keys, it goes against everything arrays stand for, therefore this isn't really an acceptable answer sorry.

Comment: You are absolutely right on the duplicate keys there! That's what you get on trying to code without testing it first from the top of your mind! At-least I got the filterAny right..

Comment: Anyways you marked your one as the accepted one.. Thought.. you should probably return something there ;).

Answer (score 0):

In DataList, wording 'Filter' shouldn't be presented in filter() function.

Correct syntax should be

```
$things->filter('PublicationDate:ExactMatch', $filters);
```

Had a look at https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.2.1/search/filters/ExactMatchFilter.php#L51

Passing array() to ExactMatchFilter should meet your requirement.